# Combine polymorphic scopes with or

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, polymorphism

How can I combine two scopes to get both results of them in one query, when they are polymorphic associations? I have this models:

```
class Vendor < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :shipping_method_registers, as: :shipper
  has_many :shipping_methods, through: :shipping_method_registers
end

class City < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :shipping_method_registers, as: :shipper
  has_many :shipping_methods, through: :shipping_method_registers
end

class ShippingMethodRegister < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :shipping_method
  belongs_to :shipper, polymorphic: true
end

class ShippingMethod < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :shipping_method_registers, dependent: :destroy, autosave: true
  has_many :city_zones, through: :shipping_method_registers, source: :shipper,
                        source_type: "City"
  has_many :vendors, through: :shipping_method_registers, source: :shipper,
                     source_type: "Vendor"
end
```

I want to get the shipping methods of a vendor AND a city combined, but only distinct results. I tried it with

```
> vendor.shipping_methods.or(city.shipping_methods)
ArgumentError: Relation passed to #or must be structurally compatible. Incompatible values: [:joins]
from /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb:634:in `or!'
```

And also with

```
> vendor.shipping_methods.merge(city.shipping_methods)
```

But this only returns the shipping methods of the city. I could merge them in Ruby, but I'd like to do it in one query.